# Soft keyboard is moving my layout up even I used windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"

Tags: android, keyboard

Soft keyboard is moving my layout up even I used windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize". It is happening for only device meizu m3 note.

```
<activity
        android:name=".v2.activities.VideoFullViewActivity"
        android:label="Video Full View"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:parentActivityName=".v2.activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SamosaBaseTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: Add your code, MenifestEntry, and layout in question Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: try with **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`**

Comment: thank you but it is also not working.